# Pass instance name as argument from several UI controls to a single function in Python-Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel

I'm developing a UI in python for maya, and I'm trying to do a function that performs an action when a frameLayout expands, in this case I have several "frameLayout" objects and I would like to use a single function "fl_expand", instead of one for each object

```
def fl_expand(*args):
    print args        

with frameLayout("layout1", collapsable=True, expandCommand=fl_expand):
   ...

with frameLayout("layout2", collapsable=True, expandCommand=fl_expand):
   ...
```

but I don't know how to pass the instance name as argument to the function, I tried:

```
with frameLayout("layout1", collapsable=True, expandCommand=fl_expand("layout1")):
   ...
```

But of course I  get this error:

```
# Error: TypeError: file /usr/autodesk/maya2018/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymel/internal/pmcmds.py line 134: Invalid arguments for flag 'ec'.  Expected string or function, got NoneType #
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have something like that:

```
def fl_expand(*args):
    print(args)

def frameLayout(name, collapsable, expandCommand):
    print("frameLayout: " + name)
    expandCommand('foo')

frameLayout("layout1", collapsable=True, expandCommand=fl_expand)
```

What you want is to call the *fl_expand* function with the first argument already filled with the name of the layout. To do that, you can use a partiel function. See the documentation for [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial).

You can try:

```
import functools

frameLayout("layout1", collapsable=True, expandCommand=functools.partial(fl_expand, "layout1"))
```

Of course, it could be laborious if you have a lot of calls like that. You can also define your own *frameLayout* function:

```
def myFrameLayout(name, collapsable, expandCommand):
    cmd = functools.partial(fl_expand, name)
    return frameLayout(name, collapsable, cmd)

myFrameLayout("layout2", collapsable=True, expandCommand=fl_expand)
```